# After redirect code still executing from previos page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

How `System.out.println("")` is executed after response has been redirected to other resource.

In my code:

```
res.sendRedirect("/more_value_in_param/display.jsp");
System.out.println("to avoid penalty and disconnection");
```

Why in console `to avoid penalty and disconnection` is being displayed since response has been already redirected to `display.jsp`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sendRedirect()` method does not halt the execution of your method.
You should either branch your code in such a way that the call to `sendRedirect()` is the last statement in your method or explicitly call `return;` after calling `sendRedirect()`.

Answer (score 0):

Sending a redirect does not break the bean-lifecycle, so the following code is executed.

Answer (score 0):

res.sendRedirect() does not break control flow within that method, but does have effects on the use of the servlet response.

A response is sent to the client with the new URL, and within the program flow of res.sendRedirect(), the response should be considered to be committed.

Good information is found in the [HttpServletResponse javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29) as well as "Myth2" listed in [Control Flow Myths busted in Java](http://paladion.net/blogs/control-flow-myths-busted-in-java/).

I would also research the difference between sendRedirect and forward to get some insight on the client/container relationship at play.